# Installing Ubuntu 32bit 12.04.3 on Older HP ZD7000 Laptop - No Icons, No Kbd Action

Tags: 12.04, installation

After installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 on an old HP Pavilion zd7000 the display is pretty and there is a User Name and Password dialog. After entering the password, the display has a vertical line on the left - but no icons. The mouse can move the cursor but that is the extent of any interaction. I cannot create a terminal window with keyboard key sequence either.

Here is what I did:

1. Old HP Pavilion zd7000 running Windows 7
   .
2. Ran DBAN nuke to wipe disk.
3. Installed Ubuntu (English, -5GMT) - all installation options and dialogs appeared to work fine.
4. Removed disk when prompted.
5. Power off, then on.
6. Ubuntu booted up and displayed the login dialog and a gray bar across top containing some symbols/icons toward the right side of the bar. No other icons present.

Should I just get a newer machine?

Thanks,
Henry

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't get a newer machine if Windows 7 worked fine on your machine before you installed Ubuntu. But, what version of Windows 7 was the laptop running? 32-bit or 64-bit? If it was 64-bit I would recomend using the 64-bit version of Ubuntu to see if that helps, and if it doesn't, then I would recommend purchasing a newer machine.

Comment: >what version of Windows 7 was the laptop running? 32-bit or 64-bit? The Laptop was running 32bit. I need Ubuntu because I'm developing Ada software and Ubuntu seems to be better than Windows7 for that purpose.

Comment: Just checked online and your laptop was released in 2004, so I'm sorry but I doubt Ubuntu will run properly on that old of a laptop. I highly recommend purchasing a newer laptop, such as one of the latest Pavilion dv7's.